# SVG different display depends on the html tag

Tags: angular, angularjs, svg, sass

im using Angular 15. I noticed weird thing, when i add svg circle by  tag it displays properly, but when i put it as just raw svg it displaying weird. See screenshots.

Icon added by img tag:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAEF6.png)
Icon added just by raw svg:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiLS9.png)

Icon code:

```
<svg id="Group_10215" data-name="Group 10215" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip-path">
      <rect id="Shape_103" data-name="Shape 103" width="20" height="20" rx="10" fill="none" stroke="#140f4b" stroke-width="1.5"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <g id="Shape_103-2" data-name="Shape 103" fill="none" stroke="#140f4b" stroke-width="1.5">
    <rect width="20" height="20" rx="10" stroke="none"/>
    <rect x="0.75" y="0.75" width="18.5" height="18.5" rx="9.25" fill="none"/>
  </g>
  <g id="Mask_Group_109" data-name="Mask Group 109" clip-path="url(#clip-path)">
    <path id="Path_12329" data-name="Path 12329" d="M11,0H0V22H11Z" transform="translate(-1 -1)" fill="#140f4b"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Anybody know what going on?

I would like to display circle svg properly by adding raw svg to the html

Comment: Probably you have multiple inlined svg elements with the same ID `clip-path` . In this case the first instance is applied as a clip path. If it doesn't match an elements bounding box (so it fits element A but not element B) you might not see any clipping (or an undesired one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like commented you probably have more IDs that are the same and the clip-path then messes up. In general IDs must be unique and then try to avoid using too many of them. You could define the clip-path in a separate SVG element and then let all the other elements that need that clip-path refer to it.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="0" height="0"
  style="position:absolute">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip-path">
      <rect width="20" height="20" rx="10" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20"
  viewBox="0 0 20 20">
  <g fill="none" stroke="#140f4b" stroke-width="1.5">
    <rect width="20" height="20" rx="10" stroke="none"/>
    <rect x="0.75" y="0.75" width="18.5" height="18.5"
      rx="9.25" fill="none"/>
  </g>
  <g clip-path="url(#clip-path)">
    <path d="M11,0H0V22H11Z" transform="translate(-1 -1)"
      fill="#140f4b"/>
  </g>
</svg>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20"
  viewBox="0 0 20 20">
  <g fill="none" stroke="#140f4b" stroke-width="1.5">
    <rect width="20" height="20" rx="10" stroke="none"/>
    <rect x="0.75" y="0.75" width="18.5" height="18.5"
      rx="9.25" fill="none"/>
  </g>
  <g clip-path="url(#clip-path)">
    <path d="M11,0H0V22H11Z" transform="translate(-1 -1)"
      fill="#140f4b"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

You could also simplify you SVG (and remove all the IDs):

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20"
  viewBox="0 0 20 20">
  <path d="M 10 0 a 1 1 0 0 0 0 20 z" fill="#140f4b" />
  <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="9.25" stroke="#140f4b"
    stroke-width="1.5" fill="none" />
</svg>
```